# CakePHP, Query from Model

Tags: php, cakephp

How I can execute a SQL query in CakePHP.

I want to make some like this code

```
    $employees = $this->Employee->find('all');
```

but introducing my own SQL statment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert into your Model a function that executes your SQL statment,

```
public function get_employees() {
     $sql = 'select * from employees';         
     $data = $this->query($sql);
     return $data;
 }
```

And call this function like this way:

```
 $employee = new Employee();
 $data = $employee->get_employees();
```

Comment: Its unnecessary. There is solution with one line below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495160/cakephp-query-from-model/22505493#22505493

Answer (score 2):

In model you can't write model name. Its already detected. Use only

```
$this->find('all');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your statement is inside EmployeesController.php

```
$employeeRows = $this->employee->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('id' => 100)));
```

if you are in another controller, you have to load the model before the find

```
$this->loadModel('employee');
```

if you are in a view, you can write a helper and use raw sql

The cakephp website also offers the following controller logic

```
$this->Picture->query("SELECT * FROM pictures LIMIT 2;");
```